# Trying to get steam user inventory on website with json/jsonp in javascript not working

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, steam, inventory

I am trying to get a users inventory to display on my website in javascript, I am not doing this in php because I don't want an index.php file (is it even possible? I don't know how all these gambling sites do it but they don't have index.php files etc, but can't find the code in their source).

code:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561197990326241/730/2?l=english&count=5000',
       dataType: 'JSONP',
       jsonpCallback: 'callback',
       type: 'GET',
       success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       }
   });
```

And the error is: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :' on line '2?l=english&count=5000&callback=callback&_=1512159196779:1' this is what I see in my browser console, I have searched on the internet and tried a several different things but they all give an error, and most of the other people that did this either did it in php or there was never really a specific answer posted. 
And after getting this to work, I need to be able to get to use this object, so would I have to put all my code relating to this json call inside the success: function, function? Or can I access the json outside that ajax request?

Comment: Not sure that's how a jsonp request is meant to work. See https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/ for some examples. P.S. A site doesn't have to have an index.php in order to have server-side code - 1) there's such a thing as extensionless URLs (where you can't see it's .php, but it resolves to a script anyway) and 2) there are other server-side languages than PHP.

Comment: With `jsonp` the callback you give it is the javascript function on your page that the response should call with the results.  Example, if you gave it "receiveData", then the response from the request would be something like `<script>receiveData(...someJsonOrSomeInputs...);</script>` which would be executed with the global eval.  Which this isn't an automatic thing.  The endpoint has to be explicitly developed to know to return this kind of response when requested.

Comment: Which calling `http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561197990326241/730/2?l=english&count=5000&callback=test` in the url returns just pure json, so I would guess this endpoint is not capable of processing a jsonp request in the first place.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have decided to stop doing it with javascript, just created something in php and it's already working, so I'll continue using that now!